# Full-width secondary navbar inside parent navbar with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a pretty simple double-navbar effect with Bootstrap.  The only problem I have right now is that the second/bottom navbar isn't stretching across the whole browser width.  Here's my code...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" style = "line-height: 30px;">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" style="color:#fff;"></span>
          </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style = "line-height: 30px;">brand</a> 

        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- <li><a href="#contact">Button</a></li> -->
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->

        <!-- this is the second navbar element that never takes up the full width available-->
        <div class="nav navbar-default" style="background-color: #66CCFF;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav><!-- /.navbar -->
```

I've played with various different navbar types and css styles (e.g. width:100%), but I can't seem to figure out how to make the second navbar (i.e. the one containing the 3 glyphicons) the same width as its parent.

Really appreciate any ideas on what I might be doing wrong!

Comment: because you nested the navbars, the outer navbar has padding. either un-nest them or remove the padding from the outer navbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `container-fluid` instead of `container` since latter has a fixed width.

`.container-fluid` still contains CSS rules for padding. You may try to overwrite it using custom class.

```css
.container-fluid.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}
.no-padding .navbar-header {
  padding-left: 10px; /* Align the Brand text */
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .no-padding .navbar-nav {
    padding-left: 10px; /* Align the icons on small screens */
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" style="line-height: 30px;">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" style="color:#fff;"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="line-height: 30px;">brand</a> 

    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- <li><a href="#contact">Button</a></li> -->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.nav-collapse -->

    <!-- this is the second navbar element that never takes up the full width available-->
    <div class="nav navbar-default" style="background-color: #66CCFF;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
<!-- /.navbar -->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar > .container {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

just removing the padding from container changes all the instances of container on your page.

you then want to add padding back to your navbar-header

```
.navbar > .container {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.navbar .navbar-header {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```